# Check for a column in pandas dataframe for all elements if they are in a set of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have a pandas DataFrame `df` and a set of values `set_vals`.

For a particular column (let's say `'name'`), I would now like to compute a new column which is `True` whenever the value of `df['name']` is in `set_vals` and `False` otherwise.

One way to do this is to write:

`df['name'].apply(lambda x : x in set_vals)`

but when both `df` and `set_vals` become large this method is very slow. Is there a more efficient way of creating this new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem is the complexity of `df['name'].apply(lambda x : x in set_vals)` is O(M*N) where M is the length of `df` and N is the length of `set_vals` if `set_vals` is a list (or another type for which the search complexity is linear).

The complexity can be improved to O(M) if `set_vals` is hashed (turned into `dict` type) and the search complexity will be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for you, it is called MapReduce.

You can read about it [HERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/map_reduce/map_reduce_introduction.htm)

In general, it is a programming model for processing big data in parallel on multiple nodes.

There is a video that explains and shows an example for MapReduce: [MapReduce Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhisPejz-6c&ab_channel=MohammadRafibarakzai)

Answer (score -1):

It is a complex problem with a simple solution, you can try to run multiple threads with this for loop:

let's say `[0:i], [i+1:j], [j+1,k]` etc.

Here is a very good explanation of how to do [multiple threads](https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python)

Also, if you are interested in more details about performance and efficiency check [this](https://www.webiny.com/blog/5-tips-to-make-your-lambda-functions-run-faster-and-cheaper) out.

Comment: Multithreading can improve performance of IO bound operations. Because this problem is CPU bound, this solution will make the problem even worse because there additional time will be spent creating and destroying threads.